# How to get single string value from Json object Android?

Tags: android, json

I have this Json statement :

```
{name=Adam Schmidt, id=43}
```

and I want to extract the value of the name,
trying this code but it didn't work

```
// parse json data
        try {
            JSONObject userObject = new JSONObject(result);
            userName = userObject.getString("name");
                    tvName.setText(userName);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: is it a valid json? http://jsonlint.com/ check here

Answer (score 2):

You statement is not valid json. Here's the sample of valid json.

```
{\"name\":\"Adam Schmidt\", \"id\":43}
```

Update:
For number value, no quotation mark

Answer (score 0):

Use [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). Super easy.

Declare a class that represents your JSON structure:

```
public class Person {
  private String name;
  private int id;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
String json = "{\"name\":\"Adam Schmidt\", \"id\":43}";
String userName = new Gson().fromJson(json, Person.class).getName();
tvName.setText(userName);
```

This is much better than haphazardly parsing chunks with various `get` methods all over your code. Plus you get a nice object to pass around and use in your object oriented code.